# Ng-map disappears if info-window has contents

Tags: angular, ng-map

I have an ng-map and am trying to pop up an infoWindow on marker click. When I try to add the infoWindow in the html, the map disappears with no errors in the console. Here is my html:

```
<div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"
         map-lazy-load-params="{{googleMapsUrl}}">
        <ng-map center="41,-87" zoom="3" on-click="mapClicked()">

            <info-window id="marker-iw">
                <div ng-non-bindable="">
                    hello
                </div>
            </info-window>

        </ng-map>
    </div>
```

If I remove "hello", the map shows up just fine, but the infoWindow is empty. How do I get the map and infoWindow to show up?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this page, I found the solution: https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/648

I simply needed to add default-style="true" to the ng-map tag:

```
<ng-map center="41,-87" zoom="3" on-click="mapClicked()" default-style="true">
```